# What's the point of passing an argument of the same type of the class?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I saw an example that try to explain inheritance in Java. The class Employee, which is the base class, has three instance variables and three constructors. it is as follows:

```
public class Employee{
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Employee(){

        name = " No Name!";
        id = 00100;
    }

    public Employee(String n, int i){

        name = n;
        id = i;
    }

    public Employee (Employee originalObject){

        name = originalObject.name;
        id = originalObject.id;

    }
```

My question is : What's the point of the third constructor? and how it accepts an argument with the same type, `Employee` ,of the class that we are still working on ? The program has already an empty constructor and another one that passes String for `name` and `int` for `id`, so why there is an extra one that does no much more than the previous two constructors ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the third constructor is intended to make a *copy* of an existing `Employee` object.

You could probably do the same thing with:

```
new Employee(orig.getName(), orig.getId());
```

but that presumes that there are "get" methods for every property. It's easier to implement one constructor like that, and then call:

```
new Employee(orig);
```

Then, if the properties of `Employee` need to change, you would only have to change the copy constructor in one place.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a *copy constructor*, and the point of such constructors is that you are now free to modify this new `Employee` object without affecting the original, or vice versa.

You are correct that `new Employee(other)` is equivalent to `new Employee(other.getName(), other.getId())`, but the copy constructor version is much shorter and makes the intent much clearer -- and for more complicated objects that don't expose all of their state, a copy constructor has access to details that another constructor would not.  Additionally, if you add fields to `Employee`, you don't have to change all the callers of your constructor -- making your code significantly more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

The third constructor is not necessary, as you say, but it is provided for convenience to any clients of this class.

It is more concise to write

```
new Employee(employee)
```

than to pass all the parameters individually.

It may also be that the required fields are private fields and so may be inaccessible to the code creating new `Employee` instances. Your class is a good example since it does not have public methods `getName()` and `getId()` to expose these properties publicly.

Finally, passing another instance of the class makes it clear to the reader that we are making a new class, that is a duplicate or a copy of the original. Being able to express that intent clearly makes maintenance easier.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) (the article is for C++, but copy constructor is general conception).

Also this question discusses the [difference between shallow and deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

Answer (score 1):

It is for convenience and it is called "Copy Constructor" where a Employee instance is created by copying properties of an already existing Employee instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a *copy constructor* - the preferred alternative to `clone()` when we need to create a copy of an instance.